# Image not loading while using express

Tags: express

I have been trying to access my css and jpeg file from the assets folder but when I execute my express.js file the console throws this error

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4000/assets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This is my express.js file

```
var express=require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var app=express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'assets')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.send("Welcome to my node express app");
});

app.post("/show_user",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.username);
  res.json({username: req.body.username})
});

app.get("/home",function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname+"/express.html");
})
app.get("/about",function(req,res){
   res.send("Welcome to about us page");
})
app.get("/contact",function(req,res){
   res.send("You are now in contact us page");
})
app.listen(4000,function(){
  console.log("Server is running");
```

})

This is my express.html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello Glad to have u here</p>
        <img src="./assets/home.jpeg" width="100"/>
        <form action="show_user" method="post">
            <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[This is what the directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXOPN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from this:

```
href="./assets/style.css"
src="./assets/home.jpeg
```

to this:

```
href="/style.css"
src="/home.jpeg"
```

You don't want to use path relative URLs here.  You want all your CSS URLs to start with `/` so the browser won't append anything to the path-relative URL before it makes a request to your server.

Comment: I changed that path in html but its still not working :(

Comment: @ExploreWorld - Then, please show exactly  where `style.css` is located in your file system relative to the `express.js` file.  You can also look in the debug console of your browser and/or the network tab of the Chrome debugger to see exactly what request the browser is sending to your server and exactly what the server is sending back.  This is generally how you debug this stuff as you don't have to fly blind or guess, you can just directly look at what the browser is sending and what the server is returning back.

Comment: @ExploreWorld - FYI, the same issue applies to your image urls too.

Comment: I have uploaded the file structure now ..can you pls check it ?

Comment: @ExploreWorld - Now that I see your file structure, both `style.css` and `home.jpeg` are in the `path.join(__dirname, "assets")` that you are passing to `express.static()`.  As such, you reference them from your HTML as `/style.css` and `/home.jpeg` because they are in the top level of the directory that you pass to `express.static()`.  I've updated my answer accordingly.